# Obtaining class dynamically for an object serialized

Tags: java, serialization, dynamic-class-loaders

I am trying to understand how to dynamically download class for a serialized object.

I am trying to do this:

1. Create a serilizable object.
2. create a server program which serializes an object.
3. Create a client program and gets a serialized object.

Now, in the client, when it deserializes the object, it needs the `.class`. As of now, I am putting the `.class` in client code.

How can we get the class dynamically? I did search on net and came to know of "Codebase" concept. All these posts have shown just a code snippet.

How can I actually do this? I intend to use http server where the `.jar` would be. How can I do this?

Comment: Do Your search production solution, or invest in personal knowledge? 1. Java worlds has professional serializers for such requirements 2. for the 2ns the most important question how much this class has dependencies etc. Assume transport is to independent JVM

Comment: @JacekCz: It is for personal knowledge, trying to clear the concepts, which at times i just "skipped". Thanks

Comment: Theme is not so easy, class has dependence to parents etc. If override is first level of Object. You have chance send binary class file over network, decode as a real class, load by classloader (what say security-manager?) and can instantiate concrete objects. Theoretically. I never had such requirement. Things are described in basic book (thinking in java?) or some of Joshua Bloch, Cay S. Horstmann, ‎Gary Cornell. Few old java-to-java protocols are build in this way. Look in google at RMI, CORBA (never used it)

Comment: Like serialization in single evnromnet is generally known (save a object, page, personal data, with hope be deseriazet in the same machine all is ok. This is for example cache: remove binary object from memory to disk, when will be required we take it.. Ober nerwok is hard: no assume that all class are loader at remote machin, must upload.

Comment: If You have time like student, not banal task to check, will be do it by hand. If I wiil a young-man  (on the roofs) pa para pam pam . then will be serialize classes. Nice them,at, many to understand ...

Comment: You've just described the RMI codebase feature. You can get the same effect yourself by using the RMIClassLoader at both ends.

Comment: @EJP: thanks, this is what i researched. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html
however no "real" code i can find to see the concept in action. Any pointer where real code albeit small one, to cement the concepts.